# Spring JPArepository Exeption with query method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem when i implement this method in my ClientRepository :

```
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client,Long> {
    @Query("select n from Client where n.nom like :x")
    public Page<Client> chercher(@Param("x") String mc , Pageable pageable);
}
```

> Exeption:
>   Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2018-05-23 10:33:32.606 ERROR 15048 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'maBanqueApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.sid.Dao.ClientRepository.chercherClient(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong:

```
@Query("select n from Client where n.nom like :x") // You select `n` from no where
```

Change it to

```
@Query("select n from Client n where n.nom like :x")
```